# Homeomorphism between $\mathbb{S}^1$ and the spectrum of the Banach algebra of $2\pi$ periodic continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $B=\{f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb C | \;\; f\; \mbox{ is continuous and } 2\pi - \mbox{periodic}\}$. Remember that $\widehat B = \{\varphi:B\longrightarrow \mathbb C|\;\; \varphi \;\mbox{ is an homomorphism} \}\setminus \{0\}$. Show that $\Psi: \mathbb S^1 \longrightarrow \widehat B$, given by: 
>   $$\Psi (e^{it})(f):= f(t) \qquad \forall f\in B $$
>   is a homeomorphism.

**What I have done so far:**

I have already proved that $\Psi$ is injective and continuous using standard arguments involving nets, existence of angle functions defined on connected open sets of $\mathbb S^1$, and the topology of pointwise convergence in $\widehat B$, i.e.:
$$ \varphi_\alpha \rightarrow \varphi \iff  \forall f\in B:\quad \varphi_\alpha(f) \rightarrow \varphi(f).$$

Since $\mathbb S^1$ is compact and $\widehat B$ is Hausdorff, it follows that $\Psi$ is a homeomorphism onto its image.

**My problem:**

I wasn't able to prove that $\Psi$ is surjective, since I don't know a natural way to find $z_0=e^{it_0}\in \mathbb S^1$, such that, for a given $\varphi \in \widehat B$:
$$\Psi(e^{it_0})(f) = f(t_0) = \varphi(f), \forall f \in B.$$

Comment: Note that since $\mathbb S^1$ is a metric space (in particular, first-countable), you only need sequences to establish continuity of $\Psi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume there is some $\varphi \in \widehat B$ such that $\varphi\neq\Psi(z_0)$ for all $z_0\in S_1$.  Then there is a maximal ideal $M$($=\ker\varphi$) in $B$ such that for each $t\in\mathbb R$ (in particular, each $t\in[0,2\pi]$) there is some $f\in M$ such that $f(t)\neq0$.  By compactness of $[0,2\pi]$, there exist $f_1,\ldots,f_n\in M$ such that for each $t\in[0,2\pi]$ $f_j(t)\neq0$ for some $j$.  But then $f=|f_1|^2+\ldots+|f_n|^2\in M$ and $f(t)\neq0$ for all $t\in[0,2\pi]$, hence all $t\in\mathbb R$.  Thus $f$ is invertible, and $M$ cannot contain an invertible element, a contradiction.

Comment: The existence of the maximal ideal $M$ follows from the fact that each maximal ideal of $B$ correspond to $Ker \varphi$, with $\varphi \in \widehat{B}$. If I am correct, $M =Ker \varphi$ and $Ker\varphi \neq Ker \Psi(z_0)$ for all $z_0$. Why there is such $f\in Ker\varphi \setminus Ker\Psi(z_0)$?

Comment: I follows directly from the definition of maximal that if $M_1, M_2$ are maximal ideals with $M_1 \cap M2 \neq \emptyset$, then $M_1 \setminus M_2$ and $M_2\setminus M_1$ are non-empty.

Comment: Yes, $M=\ker\varphi$.  The fact that for each $t\in\mathbb R$ there is some $f\in M$ such that $f(t)\neq0$ (i.e. $f\in M\setminus\ker(\Psi(e^{it}))$) follows directly from the assumption.